# How to get these information from the client with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I get these information?
I am making a javascript (no jquery) that gets the plugins and user agent, and i want to include these also. I prefer client-side, I know how to do it with PHP.

I have seen it at http://browserspy.dk/headers.php and http://browserspy.dk/accept.php and https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes

[image]

Comment: Take a look into >document.referrer< and >navigation.userAgent<.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get all the http headers:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
console.log(headers);
```

Comment: I have tried these but it does not show the requested values

Comment: Does it not show all the values or just some, which ones?

Comment: He needs the request headers, not the response headers (= the headers sent by the client to the server).

Answer (score 0):

```
var readHeader = (function() {

  // Hidden cache for the headers...
  var _request = undefined;

  return function(name) {
    //
    // We have a request cached...
    ///
    if (_request) {
      return _request.getResponseHeader(name);
    }

    //
    // We need to get the request...
    //
    else {
      // Do the request and wait for it to complete.
      _request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      _request.open("HEAD", window.location, true);
      _request.send(null)
      while (_request.readyState != 4) {};

      return _request.getResponseHeader(name);
    }
  }
})();
```

You can try this code by thsutton documented on the below link.
https://gist.github.com/thsutton/665306

Comment: How can I print the value of it?

Comment: Before return log it down.

Comment: He needs the request headers, not the response headers (= the headers sent by the client to the server).